# Ubuntu server crashing frequently

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

i hope you can help me. i am running an ubuntu 12.04 server which i am using as a web/sql server. the server was running fine for month but now since  two weeks the server is crashing almost every day. i checked the syslog and this is what it says just before the crash:  http://pastebin.com/eJ6GmBaZ
it seems like the system is running out of ram (i have 2gb) so i increased the swap file to 4gb but its happening again. But always when i check ram there is more than 400mb free. why is my server crashing?

thank you and best regards
julian

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in related with MySQL, as it's making the server run out of memory. In ubuntu, theres a script called "mysqltuner" `sudo apt-get install mysqltuner`. It could give you some pointers of what you need to modify in your my.cnf file.